# Replace a Fragment in ViewPager after configuration change

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-orientation

I have a ViewPager with 2 pages. The first page is a list which have different layouts depending on the type and orientation of the device. In case of portrait mode the list is a classic list and in landscape mode a grid should be shown.

For those two kind of layouts I created 2 different fragments: ResultListFragment and ResultGridFragment.

Here is my pager adapter:

```
public static class GSPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter  {

    private Context mContext;
    private FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
    private AbstractResultFragment mResultFragment;

    public GSPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
        super(fm);
        mContext = context;
        mFragmentManager = fm;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        Log.v("pager", "GSPagerAdapter.getItem(" + i + ")");

        switch (i) {
        case 0: {
                // if the device is in portrait mode, use a list 

                if (mContext.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT ) {
                    Log.v("pager","return new list fragment");
                    mResultFragment = new ResultListFragment(); 
                    return  mResultFragment;
                // else use a grid
                } else {
                    Log.v("pager","return new grid fragment");
                    mResultFragment = new ResultGridFragment();
                    return mResultFragment;
                }   

        }
        case 1: {
            Log.v("pager", "return the new filter fragment");
            return new FilterFragment();
        }
        default: {
            Log.v("pager", "return null");
            return null;
        }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int i) {

        switch (i) {
        case 0:
            return "Result";
        case 1:
            return "Filter";
        }
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
     public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        Log.v("pager","instantiateItem: "+position);


         return super.instantiateItem(container, position);
     }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object){
        Log.v("pager","getItemPosition: "+object);
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }
}
```

OnResume of the Activity:

```
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.v("lifecycle", "MainActivity.onResume()");
    if(mViewPager != null)
        mGSPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

What do I do wrong? I have read several questions and answers but I cannot figure out what is the problem.

Comment: But… what is the question? :)

Comment: The replacement does not happen. Why?

Comment: Does the log show that the second fragment (landascape) is being called?

Comment: Nope. Only the instantiateItem is called, the getItem doesn't.

Comment: That's because the fragment is not destroyed, its configuration is changing, the activity gets recreated and the fragment attached again. I think you might have to destroy the adapter and create it again… I haven't thought about it tho, but I don't recall the FragmentAdapter being too friendly about these things